# WebAuthenticator always skip login page, need new login form for new user

Tags: authentication, xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-api, xamarin.essentials

I just did whatever said on xamarin.essentials web authenticator page. I can sign in perfectly but how can i sign out from google? When i try to click google icon and call this for new user, sign in:

```
            var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                    new Uri(App.AuthServer + "/mobileauth/Google"),
                    new Uri("MySexyapp://"));

        var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
```

My WebAuthenticator always skip login page if i already enter info and give me same token for user. Im just need to open login form for a new user. How can i clear this token, logout or what you call it? Please help.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1223

Comment: İ dont know what should logout end point do.

Comment: I just need to sign in with another user